# Sonarqube v.4 TFS task “Publish Quality Gate Result” throws error “Could not fetch task for ID”

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

We recently upgraded to SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.1 (build 11001).  We are also using the TFS SonarQube extension Version 4.3.1.  The "Publish Quality Gate Result" build step fails with the message:

```
[SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
[SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AWRg8urbC5nyQrURbDKL'
```

This only happens on the linux build agent.  It doesn't happen on the Windows build agent.  What's also interesting is that the output from the "Run Code Analysis" step seems to indicate a different task ID:

```
=========== Run Code Analysis Output ===========
More about the report processing at http://sonarqube:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWSFWzxYmaH45QFNcZ_C

=========== Publish Quality Gate Result Output ===========
[SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AWRg8urbC5nyQrURbDKL'
```

The URL from the Code Analysis step is valid and returns a json response containing all of the data about the task.  If I replace the ID in the URL with the ID from the Publish step, I get an error json response with the message "No activity found for task".

How can this be fixed so the build step doesn't fail?

**UPDATE - FIXED**

After setting `system.debug=true` on the build, I noticed that there were two report-task.txt files that were being processed by the Publish Quality Gate Result Task:  `/agent/_work/2/.sonarqube/out/.sonar/report-task.txt`  and `/agent/_work/2/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt`.  The task reads the contents of those files to get the URL and Task ID for the SQ analysis. The second was left over from an older build and contained an invalid task ID.  Removing that file fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you set proxy for SonarQube or TFS server? Have you tried to deploy a new Linux build agent and try it again? Whatever please refer to [this similar thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/1W8raF6ZMVM)(Olivier's reply) and this blog: [VSTS - BITNAMI SONARQUBE INTEGRATION WITH HTTPS ( SSL ) SUPPORT](https://bimar-arkas.blogspot.com/2018/04/vsts-bitnami-sonarqube-integration-with.html )for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can occur if the build directory contains a `report-task.txt` file left over from a prior build.  Make sure there are no `report-task.txt` files in the build directory by setting the `Clean` option to `true` in the build configuration.

Comment: Where do you set the Clean option? Like where is the "build configuration" you mention?

I only found sonar.dbcleaner.cleanDirectory and it is set to true on my side. Still get the same error :/

Comment: In TFS, the clean option is display in the 'Get Sources' step of the build configuration.  You have to go to the edit view of the build, click on 'Tasks', click on 'Get Sources', and you will see the clean option there.  See this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2PwTGtw

Comment: Thanks, removing the old report-task.txt fixed the problem.